# Uniform convergence of $\frac{f(xt)}{f(t)}$ as $t\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, monotone-functions

Let $f(x)$ decrease monotonically to $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Suppose $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{f(xt)}{f(t)} = x^p$ for all $x>0$ and some $p<0$.

Can this convergence be nonuniform in $x$?

Comment: There should be conditions on $x$ and $p$ right? For example, if $x \neq 1$, $x > 0$ and $p > 0$, then this limit clearly cannot hold for any monotonically decreasing $f$. This convergence also cannot happen for $x=0$ no matter what value $p$ takes.

Comment: I added conditions on $x$ and $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $(1,\infty)$ the function $f(x)=\frac 1 {\ln\, x}$ is decreasing and $\frac {f(xt)} {f(t)} \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$. But this convergence is not uniform as seen by putting $x=t$. [Here $p=0$].

Comment: Thank you. What if $p<0$?

Comment: If $p < 0$, what happens for $f(x) = \dfrac{x^p}{\ln x}$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yes, your example works when $p <0$.